# Google Analytics get all user_ids that have visited a page

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I'd like to grab all the `user_id`s that have visited a certain page.

In JS I did this.

```
  var user_id = <?php echo $user_id?>;
  ga('create', 'XXXXXX', 'auto');
  ga('set', '&uid', user_id); // user_id is a variable set by my app.
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

In PHP I'm grabbing data:

```
 $data = $analytics->data_ga->get(
                  'ga:' . $profileId, 
                  '2015-12-14', 
                  date("Y-m-d"),
                  'ga:visits',
                  [
                    'filters' =>  'ga:pagePath=~^'.$path, 
                    'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath,ga:date',
                    'metrics' => 'ga:pageviews',
                    'sort' => '-ga:pageviews'
                  ]
                );
```

Where in my PHP code do I access `&uid` (or `userId` as I've seen it called) to access all the `user_id`s that have visited `$path`?

Comment: Did you create a custom dimension to store the values?

Comment: I did not. I only added the `&uid`. Why need custom dimension *and* `&uid`? What's the point of the `&uid` if not to store the user_id?

Comment: Setting it through &uid just enables it for the User ID views, but if you want to do more with it, then you also need to send it to a custom dimension so that it would be available for other reports.

Comment: good to know thanks!